# x-pack alert plugin in kibana 6.6.1

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-6, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am working with elasticsearch 6.6.1 and kibana 6.6.1.Upon installing x-pack plugin it is giving the error "you are using the OSS-only distribution of Kibana.  As of version 6.3+ X-Pack is bundled in the standard distribution of this software by default; consequently it is no longer available as a plugin. Please use the standard distribution of Kibana to use X-Pack features." How can I access the watcher UI along with x-pack plugin